Parse Undefined Symbols PFCloud
I have an iOS app that I used CocoaPods to install Parse. My Podfile is:
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'EYC' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for EYC
pod 'Parse'
pod 'SquareInAppPaymentsSDK'

end

On my code I have imported both Parse and Bolts. I run some code that uses Parse, and even autocomplete suggestions works fine for me, so I know it can see the Parse code. However, when I try to build, I get four errors.
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFCloud

Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFObject

Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFUser

Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've tried deleting the Podfile, doing a pod deintegrate and pod install again, but nothing seems to work.
If I comment out the code that references anything with Parse, it builds fine, even with the @import Parse; and @import Bolts; still there.
